# Compose multipart/form-data AJAX POST for JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

How to exactly reproduce following POST request data in JQuery AJAX?

```
<form action="/updateinfo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue5"><br>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="thevalue6"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'reproduce'? As in reproduce in javascript?

Comment: "Reproduce" means: achieve the same POST request payload using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can achieve the same effect(without redirecting) using:

```
var form = new FormData($('form')[0]);

$.ajax({
        url: "/updateinfo",
        type: "post",
        data: form,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

You need `contentType` set to false in order to make sure it is not added in the HTTP header. Also, set `processData` to false to prevent jQuery from trying to convert your data into a string.